# Dependency Property design data

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties, design-data

I have a UserControl that has an ObservableCollection dependency property with a property changed callback. The callback rebuilds the nodes in a TreeView control. This all works fine but I would like to be able to have design data. Unfortunately, neither the constructor, the callback nor a default value function call is called by the designer unless I embed my control in another. Is there a way loading default data in this scenario?

Below is the code behind for my control

```
    public partial class ScheduleResourcesSummaryTreeView : UserControl
{
    public ObservableCollection<PerformanceProjection> SelectedPerformances 
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<PerformanceProjection>)GetValue(SelectedPerformancesProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedPerformancesProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyProperty.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedPerformancesProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedPerformances", 
            typeof(ObservableCollection<PerformanceProjection>), 
            typeof(ScheduleResourcesSummaryTreeView), 
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                new ObservableCollection<PerformanceProjection>(),
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender, SelectedPerformancesChanged)
            );


    private static void SelectedPerformancesChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(d is ScheduleResourcesSummaryTreeView resourcesTree)) return;
        resourcesTree.ResourcesTree.Items.Clear();
        var sessions = e.NewValue as ObservableCollection<PerformanceProjection> ?? new ObservableCollection<PerformanceProjection>();

        if (sessions.Count == 0) return;
        var projections = sessions.SelectMany(x => x.ResourceBookingProjections);

        TreeNode<ResourceBookingProjection> resourceBookingTreeRoot = new RvtSummaryTree(new ObservableCollection<ResourceBookingProjection>(projections), "");
        foreach (var treeNode in resourceBookingTreeRoot.Children)
        {
            resourcesTree.ResourcesTree.Items.Add((TreeNode<ResourceBookingProjection>)treeNode);
        }
    }

    private static ObservableCollection<PerformanceProjection> DefaultCollection()
    {
        var prop = DesignerProperties.IsInDesignModeProperty;
        var designMode = (bool) DependencyPropertyDescriptor
            .FromProperty(prop, typeof(FrameworkElement))
            .Metadata.DefaultValue;
        if (!designMode)
            return new ObservableCollection<PerformanceProjection>();

        var designdata = new PerformanceProjectionsViewModelDesignData();

        return designdata.SelectedPerformances;

    }

    public ScheduleResourcesSummaryTreeView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: As a note, you should never set a default value other than `null` in the property metadata of a collection type property. Since metadata is static, you would reuse the same collection for all instances of your control. Instead call `SetCurrentValue(SelectedPerformancesProperty, new ObservableCollection<PerformanceProjection>())` in the control's constructor.

Comment: It is also unnecessarily restrictive to use ObservableCollection as property type. What if a user of your control wants to use a different INotifyCollectionChanged implementation? Better use the most simple possible collection type and do a runtime check if it implements INotifyCollectionChanged.

Comment: Thanks for that. Any idea how I might specify design data or is that not possible?

Comment: A design time only viewmodel or resource seems like an obvious candidate. I have no idea how that's going to fit in with all the rest of whatever you have though.